# How to set a Child View that spans multiple rows Programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, android-gridlayout

I'm getting an Illegal Argument Exception when running this Activity. Could someone point out why? My comment about the Specs will hopefully lead you to my misunderstanding of this code:

```
[Activity(Label = "Views/Layouts/GridLayout/3. Form (Java)", MainLauncher = true)]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new string[] { })]
  public class GridLayout3 : Activity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      base.OnCreate(bundle);


      SetContentView(Grid(this));
      //SetContentView (Create (this));
    }

    public static View Grid(Context context) {
      GridLayout gL = new GridLayout(context);
      gL.AlignmentMode = GridAlign.Bounds;
      gL.UseDefaultMargins = true;
      //gL.ColumnOrderPreserved = false;
      //gL.RowOrderPreserved = false;
      gL.RowCount = 5;
      gL.ColumnCount = 5;

      //I want these Specs to tell the View to take up 2 rows of space. 
      //IE, (row 0-indexed) of 3 and 4 in column 4 should contain 
      //the same button
      GridLayout.Spec specialRowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(3, 4);
      GridLayout.Spec specialColSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(4);

      bool keyIsSpecial = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < gL.RowCount; i++) {
        GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(i);

        for (int v = 0; v < gL.ColumnCount; v++) {
          GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(v);
          Button bt = new Button(context);
          bt.Text = "Tester";
          if (i == 3 && v == 4) {
            keyIsSpecial = true;
          }
          if (keyIsSpecial) {
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.RowSpec = specialRowSpec;
            param.ColumnSpec = specialColSpec;
            param.Height = 100;
            gL.AddView(bt, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(param));
            return gL;
          } else {
            gL.AddView(bt, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col));
          }
          if (v == gL.ColumnCount - 1) {
            v = 0;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return gL;
    }
```

The exception is thrown when I add the view with the special Specs: `gL.AddView(bt, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(param));`

Here's the link to the GridLayout.Spec documentation that I may be misunderstanding: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec.html

I've also tried exchanging the second argument to my specialRowSpec to use total size (height) instead of the index of the row. For example: `GridLayout.Spec specialRowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(3, 2);` This just gives me a 5 by 5 grid of buttons with no buttons spanning multiple rows.

Any questions?

Comment: why don't you just call gL.AddView(bt, param); instead of new gL.AddView(bt, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(param));

Comment: I am now. I was transitioning from using 2 Specs the only arguments to the overload of LayoutParams like: new GridLayout.LayoutParams(Spec1, Spec2)